# Как сравнить время, которое я получил в результате парсинга со своим временем?

Tags: python

Снова здравствуйте.
На одном сайте я спарсил время и мне теперь нужно сделать так, что если время на моём компьютере (или МСК время, не важно) совпадает с тем временем, которое я спарсил с сайта, то происходило определенное действие (в консоль что-то вывело, допустим)
Был бы благодарен, если поможете с этим.

Вот время, которое я спарсил в виде HTML кода:

```
<td>02:30</td>
<td>03:10</td>
<td>04:50</td>
<td>05:20</td>
```

Вот код, как я это всё спарсил:

`time_today = soup.find("tr", class_="table-success").find_all("td")`

```
print(time_today[0].text) # 02:30
print(time_today[1].text) # 03:10
print(time_today[2].text) # 04:50
print(time_today[3].text) # 05:20
```

Не обращайте внимания на тег tr и класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну да, "на тег tr и класс". Как и на ошибки во всех строках

> print(time_today[0].text # 02:30

Ну да ладно. Если ваши данные заданы в виде строки известного формата, то проще всего вашу задачу решить так:

```
import datetime
tp='16:51'
tl=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") 
if tp==tl:
    print ('Время совпало')
else:
    print ('Время НЕ совпало')
```

Comment: Ну подумаешь скобку забыл закрыть.

Comment: Если хотите стать программистом, то привыкайте, что при программировании "просто скобку забыл закрыть" не бывает.  Бывает - "скобка закрыта, программа работает" и "скобка не закрыта, программа не работает". А когда вы выставляете это в своем вопросе на сайте - то корректно написанная программа - еще  и признак вашего уважения к тем, к кому вы обращаетесь за помощью.